# How do I correctly format my code in python

Tags: python

I am  trying to find the best way to format my question, it needs to print:

```
estimated area: "2 decimal float number"
   actual area: "2 decimal float number"
```

Here is my code:

```py
print("{}".rjust(15).format({'estimated_area:.2f'}))
print("{}".rjust(15).format({'screen_area:.2f'}))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbmiW.png)

Comment: first of all use f strings

Comment: Does your code not work as intended?

Comment: `print(f"estimated area: {estimated_area:0.2f}")` and `print(f"   actual area: {screen_area:0.2f}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming 123 is the number input

```
print("".rjust(15),"estimated_area: {0:.2f}".format(123))
```